# Varnish request missing cache despite being in

Tags: varnish

I have this request in the Varnish cache:

```
ReqMethod      GET
ReqURL         /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/
```

Some PURGE requests are then send to Varnish, resulting in this list of bans:

`ban.list
200 2108

Present bans:
1458150360.937187    16 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/team0000000$
1458150360.929092     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz$
1458150360.926030     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/pitch0000000$
1458150360.923491     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/practicalrelevance0000000$
1458150360.921025     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/plan0000000$
1458150360.918480     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/target0000000$
1458150360.915931     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/duration0000000$
1458150360.913486     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/difference0000000$
1458150360.910710     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /$
1458150360.908150     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation$
1458150360.906249     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/extrainfo0000000$
1458150360.904289     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/connectioncohesion0000000$
1458150360.901930     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/challenge0000000$
1458150360.899287     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/goal0000000$
1458150360.896989     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/partners0000000$
1458150360.894324     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000$
1458150360.891701     0 C

1458150348.035639     1 C`

The same GET request is then executed again but with a MISS:

`*   << Request  >> 32790

-   Begin          req 32789 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1458150371.759282 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1458150371.759282 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 43526
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: localhost:8088
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: no-cache
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      Referer: http://localhost:8088/organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/?elements=paths
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   ExpBan         3 banned lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 32791 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1458150371.779571 0.020289 0.020289
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: gunicorn/19.2.1
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 16 Mar 2016 17:46:11 GMT
-   RespHeader     X-Caching-Mode: with_proxy_cache
-   RespHeader     X-Caching-Strategy: HTTPCacheStrategyWeakAdapter
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, s-maxage=31104000
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding, X-User-Path, X-User-Token
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-User-Path, X-User-Token
-   RespHeader     ETag: W/"0|1|2016-03-16 13:44:05.887212+00:00|None|None"
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32790
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1458150371.779598 0.020317 0.000028
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 426
-   Debug          "RES_MODE 2"
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1458150371.779641 0.020359 0.000042
-   ReqAcct        598 0 598 699 426 1125
-   End`

The ban list ist then:

`ban.list
200 147

Present bans:
1458150360.937187    17 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/team0000000$`

I know regular expressions. How can `/organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/` matches any of the pattern in the `ban.list`? It does not make sense.

I'm using Varnish 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that matches your URL is:

```
1458150360.910710     0 -  req.http.host == localhost:8088 && req.url ~ /$
```

regex **req.url ~ /$** will match your URL and any other that ends with a slash; use **req.url ~ ^/$**.

A few observations:

- you should use "==" direct comparasion since you know the full URL https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnish-cli.html#ban-expressions
- use varnishtest to debug complex situations
- try to be lurker-friendly

### About lurker-friendly ban expressions

read more [here](http://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Cache_Invalidation.html#lurker-friendly-bans)

> Lurker-friendly ban expressions are those that use only obj.*, but not req.* variables. Since lurker-friendly ban expressions lack of req.*, you might need to copy some of the req.* contents into the obj structure. In fact, this copy operation is a mechanism to preserve the context of client request in the cached object. For example, you may want to copy useful parts of the client context such as the requested URL from req to obj.
>
> The following snippet shows an example on how to preserve the context of a client request in the cached object:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
   set beresp.http.x-url = bereq.url;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
   # The X-Url header is for internal use only
   unset resp.http.x-url;
}
```

### Varnish test example for regex:

You can run it with: varnishtest test_regex.vtc

*test_regex.vtc content:*

```
# act like a backend server
server s1 {
    rxreq
    txresp
    expect req.url == "/organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/"
    expect req.http.Test == "dosent_match" 
} -start

# define & start a varnish instance
varnish v1 -vcl {
    backend default {
    .host = "${s1_addr}";
    .port = "${s1_port}";
    }

    sub vcl_recv {
    if ( req.url ~ "/$" ) {
        set req.http.Test="match";
    } else {
        set req.http.Test="dosent_match";
    }
  }

} -start

# make a client request
client c1 { 

    txreq -url "/organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/"
    rxresp

} -run

varnish v1 -expect client_req == 1
```

Comment: but why does `/organisation/xyz/proposal_0000000/comments/comment_0000001/` match one of the ban?

Comment: Because you don't force the start to be fixed, the ban with regex "/$" will match any URL that ends with slash (you should constrain the start also with: "^/$"). See here some examples https://gist.github.com/dimsemenov/10100415

Comment: I see. I missed this one, even after reading your comment. Guess I was tired. Thank you for the help!